# Question about local db used by BlazingPizza Blazor app

Tags: local-storage, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am studying the demo Blazor WebAssembly project located here [BlazingPizza](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop)

This project uses a local SqlLite database called "Pizza.db" for authentication and app-related data storage. I am trying to understand how will this db file be downloaded to the browser? Is it a hidden resource file and user has no access to it? If so, would such db file be a good solution to use instead of localStorage since user can easily manipulate localStorage values? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BlazingPizza projects consists of a Blazor WebAssembly App and an ASP.NET Core API. The database is only accessible over the API and doesn't get downloaded to the client.

Comment: Aha, understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, if you look at the BlazingPizza sample, you can easily tell it's a .NET Core *hosted* app (vs. a pure web assembly app) by noticing that among their folders in `src` are `BlazingPizza.Client` and `BlazingPizza.Server`.  This means that while the *client* is implemented using web assembly, all its data access logic occurs through the use of the ASP.NET Core Web API backend.  It's the backend (which is just a normal .NET app with full access to the framework) that is using SQLite to store data.  The web assembly portion (`BlazingPizza.Client`) simply uses standard REST API interactions to query the backend for its data.  (Importantly, a web assembly app *cannot* use the .NET SQLite drivers.)

Therefore, trying to see this as a replacement for LocalStorage misses the mark as it's not actually storing anything on the client.